# An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 1100)

Tags: ios, xcode

I got this error when trying to run an app on the device.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'xxxx@xxxx.com'. An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 1100).

Answer (score 25):

It turned out that Xcode has signed me out from my apple ID account.

So I went to

```
Xcode -> Preference -> Accounts
```

and re-logged into my account again.

and now the error is gone

Comment: I was getting underlying error code `-1009`, logging out and in again did not help, I had to restart Xcode

Answer (score 21):

You can check if Apple's systems are currently under maintenance by visiting: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: This question went from 2-6 upvotes in half an hour while Apple is down for maintenance :P

Answer (score 1):

If everything is fine with https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ the problem might be when you have low space on disk where is macOS and Xcode. Had the same problem, did remove some unused apps to free some space and after restarting Mac everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

if resigning in to your account did not work,  then choose the main project > choose target > "signing and capabilities" then check for any more errors. For my case i had to change the "team" name as well. hope that helps a bit.

Comment: i know you already solved it lol but that may help other people in the future so gonna leave that comment here.

Comment: actually, thats what solved my problem for my case, simply resigning didnt cut it for me.